# Julian Day vs the Date object to get the present day

Tags: java, date, julian-date

While referring to a particular course I came across the following code to retrieve the current day:

```
int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(),   dayTime.gmtoff);
long dateTime;
dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay);
day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

     private String getReadableDateString(long time){
          SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }
```

My doubt is why are we using this julian method instead of just directly extracting the day from the Date class object which gives the current date and time.

Comment: Two questions: 1. You're asking why your example uses `getJulianDay()` instead of directly using `System.currentTimeMilis()`? and 2. How old is this particular example?

Comment: 1. Yes..and also cant we use the Date class object directly to get the current day?
2. Regarding the oldness I have no idea but I am guessing its after 2012..

Comment: The above piece of code seems to do two things: (1) change the value of the variable `dayTime` to today at midnight, in its original time zone, and (2) set `day` to a string that represents today. How do you propose to do the first part with `Date`?

Comment: I am proposing to replace this two statements with just one statement that extracts the day part..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your application related to the Eastern Orthodox religious calendar?  As far as I'm aware, that's the only place the [Julian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) is still in use.

The Java `Date` and `Calendar` classes use the [Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) by default.  (`Calendar.getInstance` methods return a `GregorianCalendar` object unless one of two specific locales is specified.)  If your application needs to use the Julian calendar instead, that would explain this implementation.